# awk to update file based on matching lines with split

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to match `$2` in `file1` up until the `.`, with `$4` in `file2` up to the first undescore `_`. If a match is found then that portion of `file2` is up dated with the matching `$1` value in `file1`. I think it is close but not sure how to account for the `.` in `file1`. In my real data there are thousands of lines, but they are all in the below format and a match may not always be found. The `awk` as is does execute but `file2` is not updated, I think because the `.` is not matching. Thank you :).

**file 1**  `space delimited`

```
TGFBR1 NM_004612.3
TGFBR2 NM_003242.5
TGFBR3 NM_003243.4
```

**file 2**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    92149295    92149414    NM_003243_cds_0_0_chr1_92149296_r
chr1    92161228    92161336    NM_003243_cds_1_0_chr1_92161229_r
chr1    92163645    92163687    NM_003243_cds_2_0_chr1_92163646_r
chr3    30648375    30648469    NM_003242_cds_0_0_chr3_30648376_f
chr3    30686238    30686407    NM_003242_cds_1_0_chr3_30686239_f
chr9    101867487   101867584   NM_004612_cds_0_0_chr9_101867488_f
chr9    101904817   101904985   NM_001130916_cds_3_0_chr9_101904818_f
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimited`

```
chr1    92149295    92149414    TGFBR3_cds_0_0_chr1_92149296_r
chr1    92161228    92161336    TGFBR3_cds_1_0_chr1_92161229_r
chr1    92163645    92163687    TGFBR3_cds_2_0_chr1_92163646_r
chr3    30648375    30648469    TGFBR2_cds_0_0_chr3_30648376_f
chr3    30686238    30686407    TGFBR2_cds_1_0_chr3_30686239_f
chr9    101867487   101867584   TGFBR1_cds_0_0_chr9_101867488_f
```

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==NR {A[$1]=$1; next}  $4 in A {sub ($4, $4 "_" A[$4]) }1' OFS='\t' file1 FS='\t' file2
```

Comment: I have posted solution now, my solution considers that your field separators are space(since you updated you posted them now) but I added explanation how to deal with different kind of separator files too, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same. Also you could change you `FS` field separator as per your Input_file(s) too, eg--> Input_file1  is space delimited then use `FS=" "` before it and Input_file2 is TAB delimited then use `FS="\t"` before its name.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$2;
  sub(/\..*/,"",val);
  a[val]=$1;
  next
}
{
  split($4,array,"_")
}
((array[1]"_"array[2]) in a){
  sub(/.*_cds/,a[array[1]"_"array[2]]"_cds",$4);
  print
}
'   Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows:

```
chr1 92149295 92149414 TGFBR3_cds_0_0_chr1_92149296_r
chr1 92161228 92161336 TGFBR3_cds_1_0_chr1_92161229_r
chr1 92163645 92163687 TGFBR3_cds_2_0_chr1_92163646_r
chr3 30648375 30648469 TGFBR2_cds_0_0_chr3_30648376_f
chr3 30686238 30686407 TGFBR2_cds_1_0_chr3_30686239_f
chr9 101867487 101867584 TGFBR1_cds_0_0_chr9_101867488_f
```

Comment: Works great, but as I was edited you beat me to it, if I do not not want to remove non-matching lines, but rather print all do I specify that after the print as `print $0` for all lines?  Thank you for your help :).

Comment: is the `sub` only printing the matches that is in order to print matches and non-matches does a condition have to added to array[1]. That is if there is no match in array[1] the line is printed as is?  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, no it is `(array[1]"_"array[2])` checks either it is present on array `a` or not and then it gives the output.

Comment: @Chris, I will add explanation too in code in sometime.